# Showing only region of video in html5 video element

Tags: javascript, html, video, canvas, rendering

I would like to show only region of a video in html page. This should be a given pre-known pixelled-region (for example, pixels `(5, 10)` to `(670, 400)` of a video of size `(640, 480)`).

Is there a standard and/or convenient way to do that?

I found only the following sources:

- [Zooming and rotating for video](https://hacks.mozilla.org/2011/01/zooming-and-rotating-for-video-in-html5-and-css3/): Using CSS transforms to manipulate the region of the video. It has nothing to do with hiding the parts I don't want to show. I guess that I can hide it by other functionalities of CSS, but then it will hide part of the video element which I don't want to hide - the video controls.
- [Using Canvas to render each frame](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_canvas_drawimage_video): It does solve the problem, but again the functionality of video element is lost (like the video controls). In addition it requires rerendering each frame manually, which I'm not sure what is the performance cost of that.

Any better idea?

Answer (score 0):

Just add the video normally but put it inside a div or a span. Set the style of that element to "overflow:hidden" this will hide the excess, then you can set the height width.

I made an example with a youtube clip,

```
<div id="video" style="width:200px; height:200px; overflow: hidden">
<iframe width="420" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/kZAwXjidHmM" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe></div>
```

To move the video around and find a position element has to be absolute or relative.

```
position:relative; left:-120px; top:-120;
```

Comment: Thanks for replying. This is the idea of what I described in the first bullet (using HTML elements instead of CSS), and suffers the same problems: video controls are hidden, the big Play button is not in the center and is cut by the div boundaries, etc.